# Connectivity between two EC2 instances does not work

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2

I try to **ping** or ssh between these instances (A to B), neither work, both time out.

- Instance A (i-0e332d1880c8f93ae) - CentOS
- Instance B(i-0a1e4a76358059ba3) - Debian

They share VPC, and the security groups and Network ACL are properly configured. The AWS connectivity analysis tool confirmed this for both ICMP and ssh.

(Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VZo9.png , no enough reputation)

There is not any firewall in the instance B.

Both are accessible from their public IPs, but can't communicate each other.

Any idea why ?

Comment: I don't know this connectivity analysis tool. I notice there's at the top and bottom are this very specific source and destination IP. Do the security rules allow traffic to go *both ways*?

Comment: The analysis tool appears to be a new addition in Amazon. Regarding the security rules, yes, I allowed SSH and ICMP as inbound/outbound rules in both directions, but neither work. I tried allowing both directly the private IP addresses, and the security groups, in the rules.